# Understanding PHP arrays, specifically example given

Tags: php, arrays

I am new to PHP and arrays and am wanting to understand the following array.  I would also like to learn how I would go about assigning values to two particular array elements in PHP, i.e.:

```
["_gravity_form_lead"]=> array(5) { [1]=> string(4) "1000" [3]=> string(6) "strips" [2]=> string(2) "rp" [5]=> string(0) "" [6]=> string(0) "" }
```

1) What is the correct notation to define this array?

2) For the two array elements that are "", i.e.

```
[5]=> string(0) "" [6]=> string(0) ""
```

In PHP, how would I go about assigning values to these two array elements, that are NULL?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this makes you understand ,

```
$array_before   =   array('_gravity_form_lead' => array( '1000', "strips", "rp", '', ''));

echo '<pre>';
echo 'This what it looks after print_r'.'<br>';
    print_r($array_before);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything different and special than its said in the documentation

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Anyway, the concrete situation is.

```
$_gravity_form_lead = array(1=>1000, 3=>'strips', 2=>'rp', 5=>'', 6=>'');
```

As said in the documentation

```
Creating/modifying with square bracket syntax ¶

An existing array can be modified by explicitly setting values in it.

This is done by assigning values to the array, specifying the key in brackets. The key can also be omitted, resulting in an empty pair of brackets ([]).

$arr[key] = value;
```

You do modify the ones you need with `[` `]`
In this particular case:

```
$_gravity_form_lead[5] = 'something';
$_gravity_form_lead[6] = 'something else';
```

In order you want to modify all empty strings, you can iterate through the array and modify. You have two options while iterating - using reference `&`, which will modify the existent one, or creating new array.

```
foreach ($_gravity_form_lead as &$val) {
    if ($val == '') {
        $val = 'something';
    }
}
```

The output after doing this is

```
var_dump($_gravity_form_lead);
/*
 * array (size=5)
  1 => int 1000
  3 => string 'strips' (length=6)
  2 => string 'rp' (length=2)
  5 => string 'something' (length=9)
  6 => &string 'something' (length=9)
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be defined somewhat like,

```
$arrayName = array('_gravity_form_lead' => array( 1=>'1000', 3=>"strips", 2=>"rp", 5=>'', 6=>''));

/* assign null instead of '' */
$arrayName['_gravity_form_lead'][5] = NULL;
$arrayName['_gravity_form_lead'][6] = NULL;
```